# How to draw a pixel on the screen directly?

Tags: python, pixel

I'm wanting to do something like the following:

```
...
pixel[0,0] = [ 254, 0, 0 ] # Draw R at pixel x0y0
pixel[2,1] = [ 0, 254, 0 ] # Draw G at pixel x2y1
pixel[4,2] = [ 0, 0, 254 ] # Draw B at pixel x4y2
...
```

I hope to display many different configurations of pixels and colours in a short space of time -- writing to an intermediary file would be too expensive.

How should I best go about achieving this goal in Python?

Comment: You generally don't want to write to "the screen", you want to write to a window. Python doesn't include any built-in packages for interacting with a window, you'll need to choose and install something.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Right. A borderless window would also be acceptable.

Comment: If you knew how to to this writing to file, you can write to memory using `cStringIO`, although I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: With tkinter, you can create and display windows. Built-in.

Comment: Related: [How to display text on the screen without a window using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21840133/3357935)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Direct answer:**

This can only be done with OS-specific APIs. Some OSes do not allow changing pixels on the screen directly.

On Windows, you can use [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) libraries to get screen's device context with `dc = GetDC(0)` call, then paint pixels with `SetPixel(dc, x, y, color)`.

```
import win32gui
import win32api

dc = win32gui.GetDC(0)
red = win32api.RGB(255, 0, 0)
win32gui.SetPixel(dc, 0, 0, red)  # draw red at 0,0
```

Of course, what you paint this way can be erased at any moment.

**Right answer:**

Painting pixel by pixel is the slowest way to paint something. For example, on Windows, creating an image in memory then painting it in one operation is order of magnitude faster than painting with SetPixel.

If you need speed, use some user interface library for python, for example, Tkinter module or PyQt. Create a window and image in memory, then paint the image on the window. If you need to manipulate pixels, manipulate them in the image and repaint every time.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same on ubuntu?

Comment: How can I undo a pixel drawn using win32gui.SetPixel ?

Comment: @Amin: By saving the value of the pixel first by using `win32gui.GetPixel(dc, 0, 0)` so you can restore it later.

Comment: Lol this question is more than one year old. I don't even remember why I needed it

Answer (score 4):

Although it does not exactely what you say (paint "by pixel"), I like to use Python, GTK and Cairo.

In this case, you create a GTK Window, add a DrawingArea, create a Cairo context, and do paint operations.

The difference is that you have a continuous canvas with floating-point coordinates, and instead of pixels you draw geometric shapes with strokes and fills. You could even draw rectangles one-pixel-sized, and fill them, but that would not be so fast.

Also, you can take any raster object (image, pixbuffer) and render it at once. Then you could generate images in a fast sequence, and render its pixels all at once, similar to a movie.

A working example can be seen in a previous answer here (second snippet):
[quickest way to get started with cairo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575959/quickest-way-to-get-started-with-cairo/6702272#6702272)

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure if I get your question right, but I believe you should investigate some framework or middleware that give you an access to screen. I would say PyGame or Pyglet or maybe even Panda. It may be overkill a bit because Pygame and Panda is a framework that let you develop game while Pyglet is wrapper to Opengl in python, but it will let you control pixels, windows and similar with easy.

Comment: Some people also like to play around with things, not caring if there already exists a library that will do it 100 times faster.