# Basic Drawing in Python

Tags: python, graphics

As a class project, I need to create a graphics library in Python. What is the most basic way I can create windows and access individual pixels? Tkinter seems like an over kill since it already has built-in methods to draw lines. Is there a more basic way to do graphics in python?

Comment: Are you asking about making a GUI or editing graphics?

Comment: I am looking more at creating 2d images and displaying them onscreen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just create bitmaps and save them as jpeg or pngs or bmps see [Save as image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image)

If you want to get graphics contexts and draw to the screen see [How can I draw a pixel to screen in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585447/in-python-how-can-i-draw-to-a-pixel-on-the-screen-directly) or [Best Python library for drawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326300/python-best-library-for-drawing).

If you want to play with Graphical User Interfaces see [Python any good for GUI dev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115495/is-python-any-good-for-gui-development)

Comment: Thats exactly the answer I wanted. Thanks!