# How to draw to a pixel on the screen without a window in F#?

Tags: f#, drawing, screen, pixel

I found this answer for Python here [Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585447/in-python-how-can-i-draw-to-a-pixel-on-the-screen-directly). I wanted to know how I could do this in F# and what specifically do I need to import and how do I get the device context. I realize it's better to use a window but I don't want too for the project I'm working on. I'm guessing there is a way to get the width/height of the screen too.

Comment: If you understand C#, it should pretty straightfoward to translate this into F# https://stackoverflow.com/a/14398452/154766

Comment: I'll look into it now, thanks @Asik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal example that uses the `GetDC` and `SetPixel` functions to do exactly the same thing as the Python example in the referenced question:

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

[<DllImport("user32.dll",EntryPoint="GetDC")>]
extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr ptr)

[<DllImport("gdi32.dll")>]
extern uint32 SetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int X, int Y, uint32 crColor);

let dc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero)

for i in 0 .. 255 do
  let r, g, b = 255, i, 255
  let clr = (r <<< 16) ||| (g <<< 8) ||| b
  SetPixel(dc, i, 0, uint32 clr) |> ignore
```

That said, I cannot imagine a scenario where this would be a good thing to do. If you are creating a sensible windows application, you will most certainly want to draw anything in the window belonging to your app.

Comment: A screenshot application where a frame is drawn for selecting just part of the screen could be a case where you don't want an additional window.

Comment: @Tomas Petricek Do you know how to keep the drawing open after setting the pixels? It disappears after I move my cursor. Sorry, I know this is an old post.

Comment: @Alanay I don't know - it's probably best to open a new question! (This one is 7 years old :-)) I guess that to keep the pixels, you might need a window.

Comment: I'll search a bit more, if I can't find an answer I'll open a new question. :P