# Drawing Directly to the Screen in Python

Tags: python, graphics

I would like to draw directly to the screen from Python 3. For example, I would like to create a rectangle around a few icons on my desktop.

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZibw.png)
Or draw a line on the screen etc.

What are the libraries I should look up in order to do this? I prefer the performance wise solutions.

Comment: You may want to start with Tkinter - https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

Comment: As far as I know tkinter allows me to draw inside its window/canvas but not directly to the screen?

Comment: You may want to check these links: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585447/in-python-how-can-i-draw-to-a-pixel-on-the-screen-directly
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840133/how-to-display-text-on-the-screen-without-a-window-using-python