# How to draw shapes directly on screen(framebuffer?) with python on windows

Tags: python, windows, framebuffer

The title explains it self basically, I want to draw for example a rectangle on a specific coordinate on the screen, using Python, how to achieve this?
I hear PyGame mentioned frequently, but I need a solution that would allow me to click through the shape, and as far as I understand you definitely need a Pygame window to draw anything on the screen and that would prevent clicking on whatever it is underneath, am I correct?

Comment: Checked out these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840133/how-to-display-text-on-the-screen-without-a-window-using-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585447/in-python-how-can-i-draw-to-a-pixel-on-the-screen-directly

Comment: You cannot reliably draw on the screen without creating a window.