# Tracking motion of pixels on screen and sound alarm if there is a change

Tags: python, tracking

I have a question. I want to track a certain area of a screen for changes in pixels. Like when I enter a zoom conference I get in waiting area. And if there is a change (person started conference or let me in) I want computer to sound alarm.

I am quit noob in this theme so I would be greatefull if you could help me.

Comment: So you refer to a camera image which is not completely static? If it was completely static then I could imagine something like calculating a hash out of some determined points of the framebuffer, but this would not work for a camera image due to the noise in the image. But still you could track some points and have a function which detects changes in the points exceeding some threshold.

Comment: no, it's just static image which will change to another static image. And when it will happen i want to hear alarm.

Comment: What kind of operating system do you use and which programming language? I didn't try, but if you use Python on Windows, I would try to access somehow the screen buffer like they did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585447/how-to-draw-a-pixel-on-the-screen-directly Triggering some acoustic alarm should not be difficult, you can call an external programm to play some audio file. Here you see how you can call a command line from Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command